# Problema de credenciales al enviar email

Tags: php, email

Tengo 2 servidores, uno del trabajo y otro personal. En mi servidor personal, con este código envío sin problemas un email pero en el servidor del trabajo necesita complementarse con ciertas credenciales. ¿Como puedo añadirle a la funcion Mail credenciales SMTP?

```
    $header = "From: alex@xxxxx.com \r\n";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
    $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

    $mensaje = "Nombre: " . $nombre . ",\r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Email: " . $mail . " \r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . " \r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

    $para = 'alex@xxxx.com';
    $asunto = 'FHR Tecoria - [' . $categoria . "]";

     ini_set("SMTP","xxxxxx");
     ini_set("smtp_port","25");
     ini_set("sendmail_from","00000@gmail.com");

    mail($para, utf8_decode($asunto), utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);
```

PD: Evitar el uso de PHPMailer

Comment: Creo que _mail()_ no soporta la configuración _SMTP_. Por eso se suelen usar librerías.

Comment: Leyendo la documentación de [PHP: mail](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php), en los comentarios hay varios usuarios que han aportado sus códigos acerca del manejo SMTP en `mail`. Algunos dicen modificar directivas en los archivos de configuración `sendmail` y `php.ini` (Windows), otros ofrecen sus propias funciones o señalan cómo capturar los errores de `mail`, etc. Te sugiero le eches una mirada, de pronto encuentras una respuesta.

Comment: `mail` es un función muy básica y me parece que no admite autentificación, de modo que tendrás que recurrir a otro paquete o librería externa. Si no quieres usar `PHPMailer`, puedes optar por [`Pear`](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php) (es un paquete creado por de PHP, ver URL). Puedes [ver un ejemplo aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413860/5587982). `Pear` es [recomendada por PHP mismo en el Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) para tareas complejas (ver la sección **Notas**).

Comment: sugiero que se use la libreria swifmailer. https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/ Es bastante mas potente que PHPMailer, y aparte de funcional como libreria independiente, ya hay bastantes frameworks que la incluyen o indican maneras muy sencillas de su uso.